# parsing XML according to attributes with NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsxmlparser

I would like to parse xml according to their attributes and saved as dictionary .

the xml output seems like that

```
<Tracking event="firstElement">
http://www.firstElement.com
</Tracking>
```

What i am doing right now  is :

Getting tag name which is Tracking and saving URL. But in final , which URL linked event method is unknown.

I have to be save it on NSDictionary and  call it like that :

[dictionary objectForKey:@"firstElement"];

-> (NSURL *) http://www.firstElement.com

How can i be achieve ?
Best Regards ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get event in NSXMLParserDelegate:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    // reset temp data
    [self.mutableData setString:@""];

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Tracking"]) {
        NSString *event = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"event"];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [self.mutableData appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Tracking"]) {
        NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.mutableData];
    }
}
```

parse to get URL and set dictionary with `@{event:URL}`

mutableData is property MutableString

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableString *mutableData;
```

Hope this help you :)

Comment: So when i set event . How can i reach URL ?

Comment: Really don't get NSString *event part. Where we gonna use it  ?

Comment: The code only show you how to get the values you want. In your case you just have to keep the event in ivar and add an entry in your dictionary when you get the URL.

Comment: Be careful, the above code doesn't care about new line characters in XML. You may want to add a check for those in foundCharacters: method

Comment: Finally i handled with NSDictionary .  Thank you :))